# Spyder(Anaconda) does not start after forced shut down

Tags: python, crash

I stupidly tried to read a massive .bin file in Python, which resulted in the laptop freezing, so I had to force shut down the laptop entirely.

After that, Spyder does not start - I get a 'Spyder crashed during last session' message. I tried reinstalling Anaconda, I tried updating Spyder, I tried resetting Spyder, I tried restarting the laptop. Absolutely nothing works. Qt Console and Powershell open successfully.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might encounter this, I solved the problem by following the advice from here:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3868
More specifically, I deinstalled Anaconda, cleared the Roaming/.anaconda directory, re-installed  Anaconda again, and updated Spyder again using conda update Spyder in the Anaconda Prompt.